# Java, blocked queues

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, collections, blockingqueue

I've been reading about blocking queues and certain questions appeared. All the examples that i've read demonstrated only situations where there are only one consumer and one producer thread. The question is: suppose we have 1 producer and 3 consumers and in the current moment all consumers are called take() method but the queue is empty so they are all waiting for appearing first element. Which of the consumer threads will take the first element when it will appear? The consumer thread which called take() first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of the consumer threads will take the first element when it will appear? The consumer thread which called take() first?

This is tied to the blocking queue implementation as well as the JVM in question but the short answer is most likely yes.  Each of the threads will be waiting on a condition and the first thread in the wait queue will be awoken when the condition is signaled.

That said, you should not depend on this functionality since it is very dependent on the particulars of the blocking queue in question as well as the JVM and OS version.

Comment: This depends on the implementation, and in some cases like `ArrayBlockingQueue`, on the arguments when you create it.

Comment: Good point however even in the `ArrayBlockingQueue` non-fair mode, there is a queue of waiting threads and the first one that called `take()` will be dequeued.

Comment: So what will happen in fair mode? And what's the difference?

Comment: In fair mode FIFO is always ensured.   Non-fair mode is a typical producer/consumer model where a thread that just finished a job might get the new job even if there are threads waiting because of race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can tell.  The real question is: why do you need to know?  All listeners should be equivalent.  It should not matter which one handles a request.  If you have to know, you designed and implemented it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

check  `ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair)`  if fair is true,then the queue accesses for threads blocked on insertion or removal, are processed in FIFO order.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with duffymo, the idea of having multiple threads waiting indefinitely for some new elements to pop up in the queue does not sound very well structured.

Also, if you need to know which one of the consumers remove the element, that makes me think that the consumers are actually doing different things, giving life to different ouputs on different scenarios, depending on the order with which the consumers perform the take(). If that is the case you might want to have different queues for the different threads.

If you are not planning to change your code, what about having the threads to perform a poll on regular basis?

Comment: 'multiple threads waiting indefinitely for some new elements to pop up in the queue' is an acceptable design pattern and is very common.  What do you think is wrong with it?  I do agree that it should not be necessary to consider which thread gets what task.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had in my mind the image of different threads waiting on an element to pop up and that did not sound ideal, but I do not see anything wrong in a thread waiting on the element. Supposed of course that the only thing the consumer do is indeed consuming the element and performing the processing of the element itself.